# Get list of all parent modules of a child module and vice versa in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, module, yii2

I have a module hierarchy as below

`yii/web/Application` -> 
`frontend\modules\mangomod\MangomodModule` -> `frontend\modules\mangomod\modules\lemonmod\Lemonmod` -> `frontend\modules\mangomod\modules\lemonmod\modules\grapemod\Grapemod`

Bootstrapped modules are:

`yii\debug\Module` and `yii\gii\Module`

Now in `DefaultController` of `Grapemod` module I need to know all its parent modules. How?

and

Now in `DefaultController` of `Lemonmod` module I need to know all its child modules. How?

I have tried `yii\base\Application::$loadedModules` but it also provides bootstrapped modules such as `gii` and `debug` which I don't want in the list.

Here is the result of [`yii\base\Application::$loadedModules`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-modules#nested-modules):

```
[0] => yii\web\Application
[1] => frontend\modules\mangomod\MangomodModule
[2] => yii\debug\Module
[3] => yii\gii\Module
[4] => frontend\modules\mangomod\modules\lemonmod\Lemonmod
[5] => frontend\modules\mangomod\modules\lemonmod\modules\grapemod\Grapemod
```

**UPDATE**
lemonmod got its sibling module

```
frontend\modules\mangomod\modules\lemonmod2\Lemonmod2Module
```

grapemod got its sibling module

```
frontend\modules\mangomod\modules\lemonmod\modules\grapemod2\Grapemod2Module
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all ancestor modules of controller you may use [`Controller::getModules()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-controller#getModules()-detail) method:

```
$modules = $controller->getModules();
```

> Returns all ancestor modules of this controller.
>
> The first module in the array is the outermost one (i.e., the
>   application instance), while the last is the innermost one.
>
> <sub>https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-controller#getModules()-detail</sub>

---

To get list of children modules you can use [`Module::getModules()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-module#getModules()-detail). However it will return module config instead of module instance for not loaded modules - it is documented in [`$loadedOnly`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-module#getModules()-detail) parameter of this method:

> Whether to return the loaded sub-modules only. If this is set `false`, then all sub-modules registered in this module will be returned, whether they are loaded or not. *Loaded modules will be returned as objects, while unloaded modules as configuration arrays*.

If you want to get instances for all modules, you should instantiate non-loaded modules manually:

```
$modules = [];
foreach ($module->getModules() as $id => $child) {
    if (!$child instanceof Module) {
        $child = $module->getModule($id);
    }
    $modules[] = $child;
}
```

Also this will return only direct children modules - to get all descendant you need to traverse modules tree:

```
/**
 * Return all descendants of given module.
 * 
 * @param Module $module
 * @return Module[]
 */
$traverse = function (Module $module) use (&$traverse) {
    $modules = [];
    foreach ($module->getModules() as $id => $child) {
        if (!$child instanceof Module) {
            $child = $module->getModule($id);
        }
        $modules[] = $child;
        $modules = array_merge($modules, $traverse($child));
    }

    return $modules;
};
$modules = $traverse($module);
```

Comment: extreme thanks. and to find all its child module then is there anyway? Help highly appreciated

Comment: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-module#getModules()-detail

getting error `Argument 1 passed to traverse() must be an instance of yii\base\Module, array given`



*Whether to return the loaded sub-modules only. If this is set false, then all sub-modules registered in this module will be returned, whether they are loaded or not. Loaded modules will be returned as objects, while unloaded modules as configuration arrays.*

Comment: please see updation in question

Comment: you would like to add a note regarding this in official doc or should I do?